# Is it possible to transfer a file from one server to another via terraform?

Tags: terraform

I want to transfer a keytab file from the server (s1), where it was created, to another server (s2) using terraform code. While upload is not a problem, download seems not be possible via terraform according to https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3379.
Since this is not possible my idea is to implement the following workaround (the servers and my local are windows machines): I would use winrm to download the file from s1 to local and then upload it via terraform to s2. Is that a "good" way or are there other solution ideas for this? Can anybody provide a code snipped how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use "provisonier" to upload file to machines. copying file from one to another is not suitable job for terraform.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/file.html

For this you need to create file on local machine or download it from 3rd party service like artifactory, amazon s3 which is securely stored.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, can't the copying be done without a 3rd party service?

Comment: Of course it can be done. If file that will be copied on your local computer you can directly copy it.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
...
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "~/foobar"
    destination = "~/foobar"

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ubuntu"
      private_key = "${file("~/Downloads/AWS_keys/test.pem")}"
      host        = "${self.public_dns}"
    }
  }
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this seems to be an upload. The main problem is not the upload, but the download. Do you know how to download a file?